# How can I send an event from MainActivity.java to Javascript in React Native?

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-intent, react-native-navigation

Currently the following code does successfully get the text that is being shared to the app, but I am having trouble finding out how to send this event to the Javascript side. I tried creating a new `NavigationReactGateway` but my app just crashes. I'm new to Java so I don't even know if I did it properly.

```
public class MainActivity extends SplashActivity {

    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "MyApplication";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String type = intent.getType();

        if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
            if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
                handleSendText(intent);
            }
        }
    }

    void handleSendText(Intent intent) {
        String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);

        if (sharedText != null) {
            // Send event to Javascript as "share" event
        }
    }
}
```

What is the correct way to send this event to Javascript?

The app has `react-native-navigation` and there are a lot of references to an event emitter, I'm just unsure how to get the react context to emit the event. If that makes any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to modify the `handleSendText` method to the following to send an event.

```
private void handleSendText(Intent intent) {
    String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);

    if (sharedText != null) {
        ReactContext context = NavigationApplication.instance.getReactGateway().getReactContext();

        if (context != null) {
            WritableMap params = Arguments.createMap();
            params.putString("event", sharedText);

            context.getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
                .emit("share", params);
        }
    }
}
```

I also had to change from using the `onCreate` method to using `onStop`, then the react context has been initialized and my event launches whether the app was already open or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `webView.addJavascriptInterface()`

You can find documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)).

Comment: React Native already seems to have a bridge between native and Javascript. I'm trying to use what I already have available to accomplish this.